Annotations in matplotlib barplot
I would like to annotate the bars for the plot based on this groupby in a static fashion.  Given that the cluster groups all happen to have genders that roll up to the same value per cluster, static annotations will look the least busy.
How are the static annotations applied to this plot?  Basically, I am looking to label in this way: if cluster group in cluster 0,2, then annotate that bar to the right with "Male", and if 1 then "Female".  I've tried many things and just can't get it.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[0,'speciesA', 'Male'], [1,'speciesB', 'Female'], [2,'speciesC', 'Male'],
       [0,'speciesA', 'Male'], [1,'speciesC', 'Female'], [2,'speciesA', 'Male'],
       [1,'speciesA', 'Female'], [1,'speciesC', 'Female'], [2,'speciesA', 'Male']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['cluster', 'species','gender'])

df.groupby(by=['cluster', 'species']).size().unstack().plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, title='Cluster Makeup').invert_yaxis()


